# Android Studio 3.0 Go to File feature does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, android-studio-3.0

I used to jump to a file using the combination <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> until Android Studio gets upgraded to 3.0. Now the combination does not work, for instance it even can not find `string.xml`. I know that I might use *double* <kbd>shift</kbd> instead of it but it also can not find the `string.xml` file. I need to go to the file manually.

you can track the issue via this link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68742341

UPDATE: I think there is some problem with the ide for sure but they said that it did not reproduce. However I did what @LazyOne said and it worked.

Comment: You should report as a bug if it is true instead of asking here.

Comment: I just wanted to know if anyone has the same problem or I'm the one who come across because of some kind of os problem. I will also report it.

Comment: @LazyOne it worked. could you delete the comment and write it again as answer that I can accept yours as correct answer if you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fact that search for files / Navigate to suddenly stopped working suggests that indexes/caches that IDE uses might be somehow outdated/corrupted.

In such case using `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restarting IDE should help. IDE will mark all caches/indexes as "outdated" and will re-index the project on next launch. P.S. The same can be achieved by manually deleting indexes/caches folders while IDE is closed.

Please note that Local History will also be dropped (in case you are using this functionality) as in current implementation it's tightly linked to the same subsystem.

Comment: Bingo bango!! Nice find!

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me, has anyone else been able to resolve this issue? cmd+shift+o and cmd+shift+f don't work at all for me, a window doesn't even pop up.

Comment: @AngeloS *"...  a window doesn't even pop up"* That's a completely different issue. It may popup but on a second monitor .. or behind the main window (happens on some Linux distros/window managers). I suggest checking the log for a possible hints.

Comment: I don't have a second monitor and it's not behind the main window, I'll try checking the logs, thx!

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the documentation on shortcuts:

[Navigation | IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html)

[Android keyboard shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html)

> Find class: Control + N
>   
>  Find file: Control + Shift + N
>   
>  Find symbol: Control + Shift + Alt + N

Since, you are interested in finding a file "strings.xml", the **Control + Shift + N** would work fine for you.

**Update**
[Mac OS X 10.5+ keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html?keymap=secondary_mac_os_x_10.5_)

Comment: wrong. I already refer the documentation as I did. What you said is related to preferences/keymap and I use still macosx +15

Comment: **Neither your question nor the title speak about a specific keymap.** It works fine on windows. Anyway, I would update the answer to a link for the Mac OS X 10.5+ keymap. If it doesn't work, then it's more a bug as @Joshua points out.